# jquery cycle: return to the first slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The slideshow can be stoped by:

```
$(this).cycle('stop');
```

Or it can be paused by:

```
$(this).cycle('pause');
```

But how can I stop/pause the slideshow and return to the first slide at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just define it eg:

```
$(this).cycle('stop').cycle({
    startingSlide: 1
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Goto Starting Slide

```
$('#goto1').click(function() { 
    $('#s1').cycle(0); 
    return false; 
});
```

From http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/goto.html

Comment: Thank you Chacha102. My final solution is to combine your answer and Abu Aqil's answer. Unfortunately stackoverflow only allow me to pick one accepted answer =[. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's important here to make sure you're using the full version of the jQuery Cycle plugin, not the 'lite' version. The goto behavior is not supported in the lite version.